# TypeScript type safe version of Lodash's Set?

Tags: typescript, lodash

Is there a way to add TypeScript type safety to Lodash's set function?

I need to set values on deeply nested objects. The properties can be undefined, and I don't want to override other object properties.

This code works:

```
import set from "lodash/set";

type Res = {
  position?: {
    top?: { value: number },
    right?: { value: number }
  },
  color?: {
    red?: number,
    blue?: number
  }
};

const res : Res = {};

const items = ["p-top-1", "p-right-2", 'c-red-300'];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  const [type, key, value] = item.split('-');

  if(type === 'p') {
    set(res, `position.${key}.value`, value);
  }

  if(type === 'c') {
    set(res, `color.${key}.value`, value);
  }
}
```

But it doens't have type safety, eg this won't error:

```
  if(type === 'p') {
    set(res, `whatever-key-here.${key}.value`, value);
  }
```

Comment: The purpose of set is also to dynamically set properties on objects if they don't exist. That's why the specific case you're showing shouldn't fail. That said, you could create a variation of set for only setting known properties.

Comment: Maybe you could write a `set` function requiring something like the `PathInto` type described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sstur/faa75a1eb04e5b8bcf689bdb4343939b) (and the referenced YouTube video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is alike function `set` in `moderndash`, but it's missing a typesafe `set-existing-value` counterpart

(it works exactly like `lodash`'s `set`, so you may freely `import { set as setUntyped } from "lodash"` instead)

By modifying its types to be a-la-`set` rather then a-la-`assign`, it's straightforward how to implement a typesafe version of `set`:

```
import { set as setUntyped } from "moderndash";
import type { Call, Objects, Strings } from "hotscript";
import type { PlainObject } from "moderndash";
export function set<TObj extends PlainObject, TPath extends Call<Objects.AllPaths, TObj>>(
    obj: TObj, path: TPath, value: Call<Objects.Get<TPath>, TObj>
): TObj {
    return setUntyped(obj, path, value) as TObj
}
```

To use it with your splitted string you will also need a `string.split` overload:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        // typesafe 's-t-r-i-n-g'.split('-'): ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
        split<S extends string, D extends string>(this: S, separator: D): Call<Strings.Split<D>, S>;
    }
}
```

Then the example code shows errors, just as expected:
Playground: https://tsplay.dev/Nn886W

```
const res: Res = {};

const items = ["p-top-1", "p-right-2", 'c-red-300'] as const;

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i];
    const [type, key, value] = item.split('-')

    if (type === 'p') {
        set(res, `position.${key}.value`, value);
        //                                 ^!
        // Argument of type '"1" | "2"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | undefined'.
    }

    if (type === 'c') {
        set(res, `color.${key}.value`, value);
        //                              ^!
        // Argument of type '"300"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.(2345)
    }
}
```

Comment: Added issue on https://github.com/Maggi64/moderndash/issues/115

Comment: I get an error at "return setUntyped(obj, path, value)" : 

Type 'PlainObject' is not assignable to type 'TObj'.
  'PlainObject' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TObj', but 'TObj' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PlainObject'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'TObj[P]'.ts(2322)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-carlos-84yeew?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @Evanss does adding `return ... as TObj` fixes that? (see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76280420/revisions )

Answer (score 0):

First, we will need to get the possible paths that we can get. We will use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) for that. We will need some utils:

`Dot` - concatenates to strings to a path:

```
type Dot<T extends string, U extends string> = '' extends U
  ? T
  : `${T}.${U}`;
```

`DefaultStopTypes` - types on which we should stop going deeper

```
type DefaultStopTypes = number | string | boolean;
```

`PathsToFields` - accepts an object and stop types. Recursively traverses object and gets paths to its fields with dot notation.

```
type PathsToFields<T, StopTypes = DefaultStopTypes> = T extends DefaultStopTypes
  ? ''
  : {
      [K in Extract<keyof T, string>]: Dot<K, PathsToFields<T[K], StopTypes>>;
    }[Extract<keyof T, string>];
```

Example:

```
// type PathsToRes = "position.top.value" | "position.right.value" | "color.red" | "color.blue"
type PathsToRes = PathsToFields<Res>
```

`GetPropertyType` - accepts an object an a path to its field. Returns the type of the property under the given path:

```
type GetPropertyType<T, K extends string> = K extends keyof T
  ? T[K]
  : K extends `${infer Property}.${infer SubField}`
  ? Property extends keyof T
    ? GetPropertyType<NonNullable<T[Property]>, SubField>
    : never
  : never;
```

The remaining part is to write `set` function, which is pretty straightforward:

```
const set = <
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  P extends PathsToFields<T>,
  V extends GetPropertyType<T, P>,
>(
  obj: T,
  path: P,
  value: V,
) => {
  const chunks = path.split('.');
  chunks.reduce<Record<string, any>>((acc, chunk, index) => {
    acc[chunk] ??= {};

    if (index === chunks.length - 1) acc[chunk] = value;

    return acc[chunk];
  }, obj);
};
```

Usage:

```
set(res, 'color.blue', 123) // no error expected
set(res, 'position.right.value', 123) // no error expected
set(res, 'incorrect.right.value', 'incorrect') // incorrect key
set(res, 'color.blue', 'invalid value') // incorrect value
```

However, it is not enough in your case since you are using utility classes such as 'p-top-1' and split isn't typed, so you must assert the correct type with `as` assertion.

I can propose to add the following types:

```
type Position = 'top' | 'right';
type Color = 'red' | 'blue';

type StyleCreator<T extends string> = `${string}-${T}-${string}`

// type PositionStyle = `${string}-top-${string}` | `${string}-right-${string}`
type PositionStyle = StyleCreator<Position>;

// type ColorStyle = `${string}-red-${string}` | `${string}-blue-${string}`
type ColorStyle = StyleCreator<Color>;

type Style = PositionStyle | ColorStyle;
```

Redeclare items as follows:

```
const items = ['p-top-1', 'p-right-2', 'c-red-300'] satisfies Style[];
```

It is still not the solution since splitting will return us a `string[]`.
Let's create a utility type for the split that returns the exact values types:

```
type Split<Str extends string, Del extends string> = string extends Str
  ? string[]
  : '' extends Str
  ? []
  : Str extends `${infer T}${Del}${infer U}`
  ? [T, ...Split<U, Del>]
  : [Str];
```

Example:

```
// type Splitted = ["p", "top", "1"]
type Splitted = Split<'p-top-1', '-'>
```

That's it, though you will have to assert the `value` to `number`, since when you split you get a `string`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  const [type, key, value] = item.split('-') as Split<typeof item, '-'>;

  if (type === 'p') {
    set(res, `position.${key}.value`, +value);
  }

  if (type === 'c') {
    set(res, `color.${key}`, +value);
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AZWAezAFXAgGcoBeKAO2QFsAjCAJygB8ojgGBLCgcxalrZsqCIgoBuAFCTQkKAAVEwABZE82AGKcIqACZEAPHgA0ULLgKQS5OEjSYc+QkQB8ZKHigQAHsAgV9WAQUdHMnK0koKAB+KAByOMioAC4oAG8kqKiAbQBpKG4oAFFfBkQAY2ADAGsIEGx4D1N2Ll4XAF1UmGwq3NNFFTVNbT1DPDz20zDLYhcXKSyoAF9sko4Kqtr6xpM2Dm4eDqkZQlgeoy9ff0CWg9MAVUu-AJJbtvcEp+uSe6TYvCSqQABgASNJ4JYAOjB9yWQOOsmgAHEIMB5AxcIxQDMjKZ8j5njd9u9yPiri8oFsGh4-h4JoCoGTCSRQWluPBGAoMZAGKAoWD2ZyMMhaFodLo4bT0ZjeSAvhSqTtMjEoCi0dysSAcQA5bAUbVoVCIWgiIzZaU80DtFxTEVivQuZWpCgQABujAZLvdDGO5T17DYqPcBiSngJ3ygACUIH6GLoDG8eKYxCAbUl5PLAgNVOp7fojGmogA1TMkNUWzU43byNMuAAUSWwtAAVqkTEkwEplKl5MYkq7EKhkBBUkW+wBKMhuDJRP0UAPlZTICjVaxQTsqSFEMCoTjAOtxSFxccLKCL5eryEMCC6ZDlCAGaOx+OJ5MUVP1usVcqmc8r0zcLoPiTqQ07Kt+2R-tU7QxNE5BpEsxyLJwjR1oBPhkKQ5BQUQkIiLwKhQAAtFAACMk4QVBMHkAOQ4QEhWTXsAyAMBQUCUUuK7tKeSymE2zYnpIiHSIiUbEO4M7rtgRB7pwerRKkklRI4CnpFAtHDs6ND0EwwmLFwPDKMAqlpOpg6aZQ2mcnpyynn6qDYAwJnKteuiqVQdCMKeUQmsO7lWT6STCcJJxyBgO57gYWBMOGFKvkEqClnsrSHO4iZJdFtKJtk7QMp8sWBJlUSxDlDLRUlrKCkwEJgnAqBLAKFAckwsJArS2S7JCXXhbuVT3KYdUdAy2TRdx0hzgG15EKk0ZrghCKnPI0myXqHyOHE-BxAZRlxFIokAMLCI5HyuRtrBxL5EC7SJpxYCAIj7deSiORcBWvMSqXkKyiZLERYIQn9aQ-W1kgAPSg1AolLTJwByRQd0iO430fb9jiA8D-DIylv3bcA6Mo21UPLbDeoI9A5Bk49og4AwBjQytFDzNI4OQ6ch0OQwZNI2CP1Ea5+PY0CmM8yjRGXQLBySgdR2c6AiMU3LEBU89tPs45TOiVz5D0yT8OK-wauy-d9Hjf6wAFH41BrtkcRgERaOkXEpi23znCGXjABMTvxOUfM3kRADMAAMQdxDBRBKJwRDwNoJBkzlxzwMddYiObnDuEH4gFFABgWxAVt4f4PAqFnnAANRl5OkkTWnlvuHu+dENknBjbOZtQNkiKmFspgaRA1F59QW4RfucREce7FxyPBiItSDfUM749M0kKFQHWolYeQtsT0pgb7lNphAmAxNw9CaRbFCfdAqYZd94JURLNIUSr+vpybz7O-KkQqJ1gfUBAvZRyZ8L7XygLfcyEB77LCEtIb++9iDO0AQwSEl1vakQ9gHScLMKDYC8AwDEMVvCQEqDeSQcDf4IPiMfGGp9caQj7mgjBWCIY4LwQQy4xC-C6DIT-P+cRuCxmvJUK8bsjL0Igd7fhFBBExmABPFmAjHJCPNlsHh8CiCIJliguikjuC0U4LoMyOjmEFGkUo2RRjhzSB8MfXk6QlhAA)